# Multiple regression data analysis

Tags: r, regression, dataset, experiment-design, factor-analysis

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1czrXmJuxvwalDwNDLHIvt64QqNb8cSTahEEK8DIiQPM/edit?usp=sharing

the study: "right and left visual hemifields and duration of the presented stimulus were manipulated using a brief lexical decision task (differentiating words from non-words) using emotional and neutral words. (and non-words but we are ignoring that in terms of data analysis) To measure lexical decision, participant’s reaction time and accuracy of each stimulus response were analyzed." [image]
I just need suggestions/reassurance that this makes sense how I ran it in R??? Should I try a different approach or?

Comment: The data spread sheet is kind of confusing, but each row is a participant, each col. is a specific word and presentation, and each cell gives that subjects reaction time in response to that specific stimulus.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you are trying to do. Is your question to what extent ER varies linearly for linearly increasing or decreasing levels of NR, EL or NL?